# Array of strings with malloc on C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, malloc, void

For a list of reasons that I do not control, I need to create an array of strings that needs to be referenced from a void* pointer. The idea is to follow the following pattern in C++:

```
void* TP = malloc(sizeof (double) * SS);
for (int i = 0; i < SS; i++) {
  ((double*) TP)[i] = IStringToDouble(Token[i]);
}
```

Where Token is a vector and SS an int. Now, using that template, I though starting with something like:

```
void* TP = malloc(sizeof (string) * SS);
for (int i = 0; i < SS; i++) {
  ((string*) TP)[i] = Token[i];
}
```

I know that this is horribly wrong, but all the modifications I have tried starting from it don't work.

Any suggestion about how to achieve this? Is it possible?

I have gone through all the documentation about string arrays on C++ that I have found from Google or StackOverflow, but none of them covers the issue about referencing the array from a void*.

Comment: Don't use malloc in C++. Especially not with std::string.

Comment: Hi Borgleader, I know that, any suggestion to fulfill the request for the void* pointer, with or without malloc, would be very useful.

Comment: What is `Token[i]`, and how will the strings be accessed?

Comment: Hi Matt, Token is a vector<string>, so Token[i] returns a string already initialized. The strings will be used by other functions that only accept void* as parameter, but those functions have all the information required to reference the position and cast the pointer.

Comment: Could you make `TP`'s pointers just point into that vector then? Instead of trying to allocate new strings?

Comment: In other words, store the strings somewhere reliable, and create this `void *` thingy as an accessor (but not an owner) when it is needed

Comment: No, that can't be done because Token will die when the function ends.

Comment: Why `void*` and not `string*`? (You do know that any pointer, except for function pointers and pointers-to-members, can be converted to `void*`?)

Comment: Hi immibis, how would you suggest to create the string* array?

Comment: @LotherLandcraft (1) it's a string array, not a string* array (the *pointer to it* is of type string*), and (2) using `new string[SS]` like normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void* TP = malloc(sizeof (string) * SS);
for (int i = 0; i < SS; i++) {
  ((string*) TP)[i] = Token[i];
}
```

This is horrible, but I'll ignore that and explain why it's broken and how to get it working....

`malloc()` allocates memory but doesn't construct any objects in it.  For `string`, you need to invoke the constructor - otherwise the new `string` instances will contain uninitialised pointer members that the `string` object will assume are pointers to memory for the actual text data: `((string*) TP)[i] = Token[i];` will then try to ensure capacity and overwrite memory based on these garbage values.

To fix this, use the placement-new operator to construct each of the strings:

```
void* TP = malloc(sizeof (string) * SS);
for (int i = 0; i < SS; i++) {
  new (&((string*)TP)[i]) std::string(Token[i]);
}
```

You'll need to destroy the `string`s similarly afterwards by calling their destructors explicitly, and then `free()` the array.

Comment: Hi Tony, you pointed out exactly what I knew was wrong about the uninitialized strings from the memory allocation. Could you please check the "new" line? It seems that there is a parenthesis issue.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked perfectly and very similar to the original template I had in mind.

Comment: `&((string*)TP)[i]` simplifies to `i + (string*)TP`, btw.

Comment: "You'll need to `delete` the strings similarly afterwards." - no, that would be undefined behavior.  You allocated with malloc(), so must free().  But yes, you must first "destroy" (not `delete`) the strings, which you can do by explicitly calling their destructors in a loop.  This led directly to another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28057999/deleting-an-array-of-stdstring-allocated-with-malloc-in-c

Comment: @JohnZwinck: yes - careless of me.  Thanks for correcting this answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can convert any pointer to a `void*` already. You do *not* need to use `malloc`, and you do *not* need to have the `void*` pointer as the only pointer to the object.

With that in mind, why not do this?

```
string* TP = new string[SS];
for (int i = 0; i < SS; i++) {
    TP[i] = Token[i];
}

void *TP2 = TP;
```

or even this:

```
void *TP = &Token[0];
```

although, with the second method, the pointer will be invalidated if you add more elements to `Token`, and modifying the strings through this pointer will modify the strings in `Token` (since that's what the pointer's pointing to).

Comment: Hi immibis, thank you very much, it worked exactly how I wanted. I had tried a very similar solution prior to posting the question, but the use of a different variable to cast the TP array made the difference.

Comment: a `std::vector<std::string>` would be much better than `new string[]`. You can use `&TP[0]` or `TP.data()` to get a pointer to the first element of a `vector`.