# Deleting an array of std::string allocated with malloc in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, memory-management

This is a follow up from my question at: [Array of strings with malloc on C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28036732/array-of-strings-with-malloc-on-c)

As I have implemented Tony D solution, I have allocated memory for an array of `std::string` with `malloc` and then created the `std:string` for each one of the elements with `new` according to:

```
void* TP = malloc(sizeof (string) * SS);
for (int i = 0; i < SS; i++) {
  new (&((string*)TP)[i]) std::string(Token[i]);
}
```

(`Token` is a `vector<string>` and `SS` an `int`)

> I know this is not recommended, I know it is not elegant, I know there
>   are many other solutions for this array creation and filling, but I need to do 
>   it this way

The issue I encounter now is at the array deletion. As I create each `std::string` separately but the allocation for the array with a `malloc`, in my destructor I have written:

```
for (int i = 0; i < SS; i++) {
  delete (&((string*) TP)[i]);
}
free(TP);
```

But when running, the `free(TP)` is accusing a "double free or corruption".

By commenting the `free(TP)` I solve the issue for runtime (hidding the real issue), but I need to be sure all memory is released as this may cause a memory leak within the class.

So, is the deletion of each element of TP enough to free all that memory? From my understanding the `malloc` has allocated memory independently and it needs to be free independently from the `std::string` elements; but then, why do I get this error?

Comment: Don't use any `new` or `malloc` or similar things directly. Use RAII facilities!

Comment: "By commenting the free(TP) I solve the issue"... No, that _hides_ the issue.  That does not _solve_ the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're doing a placement-new to run `std::string`'s constructor on the `malloc` allocated block, but then you're using `delete` which will run the destructor AND try to free the memory (you don't want to do the second one here since you're freeing with `free()`).

You want to run the destructor manually, like this...

```
for (int i = 0; i < SS; i++) {
  (&((string*) TP)[i])->~string();
}
free(TP);
```

Comment: In other words, the matching operation for "placement new" is "call the destructor."

Comment: `string* sp = (string*)TP; for (int i = 0; i < SS; i++)  (sp+i)->~string();`  Much simpler.

Comment: Hi Nick, It worked perfectly. I had the impression that something as you showed up was happening when deleting the first element of the array, but I am not very familiar with the constructor/destructor of this std:: classes.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's clean up your code.  I suggest you stay away from `void*` for your array type.  Then you can do this, which is a little easier to read, especially on the `new()` operator:

```
std::string* TP = (std::string*) malloc(sizeof (std::string) * SS);
for (int i = 0; i < SS; i++) {
  new (&TP[i]) std::string(Token[i]);
}
```

Now, to free the strings, you have to call their destructor directly, don't use `delete` (there is no *placement-delete* operator, like you are assuming):

```
for (int i = 0; i < SS; i++) {
  TP[i].~string();
}
free(TP);
```

Now, with that said, you clearly have access to `std::vector`, so there is no good reason to use `malloc()` instead:

```
std::vector<std::string> TP(SS);
for (int i = 0; i < SS; i++) {
  TP[i] = Token[i];
}
```

Or:

```
std::vector<std::string> TP;
TP.reserve(SS);
for (int i = 0; i < SS; i++) {
  TP.push_back(Token[i]);
}
```

Or:

```
std::vector<std::string> TP(Token.begin(), Token.begin()+SS);
```